# Select using grep and sed

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have written a Bash script to select only the number in this phrase (below) and copy it into a file.

```bsh
siesta: Total = -29.649928
```

Here is my solution (at least a makeshift solution):

```bsh
grep 'Total =' h2.$i.out >> data.dat
sed -i -e "s/"siesta:"/$i/g" "data.dat"
sed -i -e "s/"Total"//g" "data.dat"
sed -i -e "s/"="//g" "data.dat"
```

Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one line:

```bsh
grep -Po 'siesta: Total = \K.*' "h2.$i.out" >> data.dat
```

Explanation:

- `-P` Use Perl-compatible regex (PCRE), which supports much more advanced pattern-matching
- `-o` Print only matching part of line (in this case, just the number)
- `\K` Don't consider the preceding as part of the match (This is a PCRE feature.)
- `.*` Match zero or more of any character (except a newline)

To print `$i` to the file in the same line as the grep output, run `printf '%s' "$i" >> data.dat` before the grep command. I assume you're running it inside a loop, so that would work like this:

```bsh
for i in ...; do
    printf '%s' "$i" >> data.dat
    grep -Po 'siesta: Total = \K.*' "h2.$i.out" >> data.dat
done
```